# Find all text between $...$ delimiters using bash script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I have a text file, and I'm trying to get an array of strings containing between $..$ delimiters (LaTeX formulas) using bash script. My current code doesn't work, result is empty:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=($(grep -o '\$([^\$]*)\$' test.txt))
echo ${array[@]}
```

I tested this regex [here](https://regex101.com/), it finds the matches. I use the following test string:

```
b5f1e7$bfc2439c621353$d1ce0$629f$b8b5
```

Expected result is

```
bfc2439c621353 629f
```

But *echo* returns empty. Although if I use `'[0-9]\+'` it works:

```
5 1 7 2439 621353 1 0 629 8 5
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: You sctually want to get *captures*, not matches. `grep` does not allow you to access capturing groups. Delimited texts are better processed with `awk`. If you want to use regex, Perl is best here. Note also that `(` and `)` are literal `(` and `)` symbols in a BRE POSIX regex pattern.

Comment: You didn't escape your parenthesis -- grep is attempting to match literal ('s

Comment: @hek2mgl How is this unclear? I think the question is clearly explained, with a reproducible code sample.

Comment: @TomLord Changed my mind, I think you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
grep -o '\$[^$]*\$' test.txt | tr -d '$'
```

This is basically performing your original `grep` (but without the brackets, which were causing it to not match), then removing the first/last characters from each match.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `awk` with input field separator as `$`:

```
s='b5f1e7$bfc2439c621353$d1ce0$629f$b8b5'

awk -F '$' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i}' <<< "$s"
```

Note that this `awk` command doesn't validate input. If you want `awk` to allow for only valid inputs then you may use this `gnu awk` command with `FPAT`:

```
awk -v FPAT='\\$[^$]*\\$' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {gsub(/\$/, "", $i); print $i}}' <<< "$s"
```

```
bfc2439c621353
629f
```

Comment: I thought OP is trying to find text between `$...$`

Comment: Yeah, but your answer returns `foo` when it finds `123$foo`  - which is not *between* `$`s

Comment: I have updated answer to use `gnu awk` command that also validates input. Believe only `awk` or `sed` can do this in a single command.

Comment: Looks good! Was also thinking about using `FPAT` (since `grep -o`, as used in the question is GNU specific anyway).

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
grep -Eo '\$[^$]+\$' a.txt | sed 's/\$//g'
```

I'm using `sed` to replace the `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping your braces:

```
tst> grep -o '\$\([^\$]*\)\$' test.txt
$bfc2439c621353$
$629f$
```

of course, you then have to strip out the `$` signs (`-o` prints the entire match).  You can try sed instead:

```
tst> sed 's/[^\$]*\$\([^\$]*\)\$[^\$]*/\1\n/g' test.txt
bfc2439c621353
629f
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is your expected output given `b5f1e7$bfc2439c621353$d1ce0$629f$b8b5` the two elements `bfc2439c621353 629f` rather than the three elements `bfc2439c621353 d1ce0 629f`?

Here's a single grep command to extract those:

```
$ grep -Po '\$\K[^\$]*(?=\$)' <<<'b5f1e7$bfc2439c621353$d1ce0$629f$b8b5'
bfc2439c621353
d1ce0
629f
```

(This requires GNU grep as compiled with libpcre for `-P`)

This uses `\$\K` (equivalent to `(?<=\$)`to look behind at the first `$` and `(?=\$)` to look ahead to the next `$`.  Since these are lookarounds, they are not absorbed by grep in the process and therefore `d1ce0` is available to be found.

Here's a single POSIX sed command to extract those:

```
$ sed 's/^[^$]*\$//; s/\$[^$]*$//; s/\$/\n/g' \
    <<<'b5f1e7$bfc2439c621353$d1ce0$629f$b8b5'
bfc2439c621353
d1ce0
629f
```

This does not use any GNU notation and should work on any POSIX-compatible system (such as OS X).  It removes the leading and trailing portions that aren't wanted, then replaces each `$` with a newline.

Comment: Because I'm finding LaTeX formulas, so e.g. for a string "for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ it's true that $\sqrt{x^2}=\abs{x}$" the expected result is "x\in\mathbb{R}" and "\sqrt{x^2}=\abs{x}"

Answer (score 0):

Using bash regex:

```
var="b5f1e7\$bfc2439c621353\$d1ce0\$629f\$b8b5"  # string to var
while [[ $var =~ ([^$]*\$)([^$]*)\$(.*) ]]       # matching
do 
    echo -n "${BASH_REMATCH[2]} "                # 2nd element has the match
    var="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"                     # 3rd is the rest of the string
done
echo                                             # trailing newline
bfc2439c621353 629f
```